# Correctly centre text panel under logo

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to achieve markup to match the below image:

[image]

Note where the red box is placed this is my company logo and I have blanked out part of the text.

The second image shows my attempt:
[image]

My css and design skills are not great and I cant get the text in the panel centered under the logo correctly and the font on the text doesn't looks as good as the jpg image I was given to work from and also the button is not centered in the panel or correct width

I am using Bootstrap v4.1.3

The HTML I have written so far is below:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
    
#centreElement {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px;
    max-width: 440px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#button-wrapper {
    float:right;
}

.centreLogo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: -250px; /* Half the height */
    margin-left: -250px; /* Half the width */
}

.panelRow {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn-primary {
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: #99E5EA;
    border-color: #99E5EA;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="centreLogo"><img src="~/images/logo-1.png" /></div>
  <div id="centreElement">
      <div class="panelRow">
  <p>You are accessing a . The access to or use of any resources without permission is strictly prohibited. Unauthorized use may face criminal or civil penalties. You are subject to our Terms of Use and may
      be monitored or recorded.</p>
</div>
<div id="button-wrapper">
  <a class="btn btn-primary">
      Accept
  </a>
</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a better way I can center the panel with the text under the logo which also needs centered separately

Comment: Have you tried using a margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto solution,
Also i noticed you said you are using bootstrap but you haven't implemented any bootstrap at all when i think that might be the easiest and best solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to create a container, which contains the company logo and the panel, that is centered to the screen:

1. A container with fixed width, and left, right auto margin
2. A container with fluid width, using *Bootstrap* grid system, e.g., rows and columns, and center justified content

To make the text and the button inside the card/panel center-aligned, you can use `text-align:center;` or the *Bootstrap* [utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-alignment) `.text-center`.

#### Fixed width with left/right auto margin

```html
<body>
    <main id="site-main">
        <div class="company-logo"></div>
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-body">
                <p>...</p>
                <button />
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

```css
#site-main {
    width: 30rem;
    margin: 3rem auto;
}

.company-logo {
    height: 5rem;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/trudcsxj/12/

#### Using Grid System

Since *Bootstrap* rows and columns are now built using *flexbox*, you can easily construct a single row and column with `justify-content:center;` to make the container centered.

With this approach, you can also pick the column width you want for different [breakpoints](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints) as well.

```html
<body>
    <main id="site-main" class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-9 col-lg-7 col-xl-5">

                <div class="company-logo"></div>
                <div class="card text-center">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <button />
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

```css
.company-logo {
    height: 5rem;
    background: red;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/trudcsxj/17/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  max-width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.content {
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
      survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
      publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">
    Hello
  </button>
  </div>
</div>
```